# Is sampling from a discrete distribution of known size random number of times with random probability distribution equivalent to a random sampling?

Tags: sampling, random-variable

What I mean to ask is if I have to choose a random number of elements(say 3) without replacement from a set(for example {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}) with a probability distribution generated by running a pseudo random number generator number of times equal to the size of the set and normalized to summation of 1.
Is this equivalent to choosing a random number of elements from the same set without replacement?
Are their any biases that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pseudo random generator is mimicking your random choice, you can think of the Pseudo random generator generating a random sequence say (1,4,3...) which is the sequence in which you make the random choice in the latter scenario. Hence they are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks. I thought the same but wasn't sure. Will have to wait 9 minutes to accept the answer.

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if you are satisfied ? Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay